# Finding string and copying cells

Tags: string, vba, excel, search

## Data

[image: Data]

## Output

[image: Output]

(Please see data and output attached above)

Here is my sample data. What I am looking for is to everytime a word from column D is found in column A, copy and paste values from Column A, B, C into the another set of columns, like image below. Here is the code I have written

```
Sub stringfinder()

Dim term As String
Dim keyword As String
Dim finaltable As String
Dim clicks As Integer
Dim impressions As Integer
Dim cost As Integer


finaltable = 2

    



For i = 2 To 900000
    For j = 2 To 50

    If Range("A" & i).Value Like "*" & Range("G" & j) & "*" Then
        
            term = Cells(i, 1).Value
            clicks = Cells(i, 2).Value
            impressions = Cells(i, 3).Value
            cost = Cells(i, 4).Value
            
            
            
            Cells(finaltable, 7).Value = term
            Cells(finaltable, 8).Value = clicks
            Cells(finaltable, 9).Value = impressions
            Cells(finaltable, 10).Value = cost
            
            finaltable = finaltable + 1
            
        
            
            
        End If
    Next j
    
Next i


            
            
End Sub
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhY0R.png)

Also for words like state and progress, it also includes words such as statement and progressive. I understand this is because I use the LIKE operator.

Any solutions would be appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATE!!!
I was able to loop through the column D using SJR's suggestion!

I still have issues with matching exact words. For words like progress and state, the code also includes words like progression, progressive and statement. Any way to find the perfect match?

Comment: You need the asterisks `If Range("A" & i).Value Like "*" & Range("D" & j) & "*"`.

Comment: You will need to loop through column D separately. testing each one against the value in a till it finds a match.

Comment: I have, using j = 2 to 10.
I am trying SJR's suggestion right now but excel just freezes up. Ill make the edit to the code above to show.

Comment: Do you really have 900k rows of data!? You are doing 9 million loops.

Comment: I have around 700k, I know it will be slow, as I have 50 keywords to search and 700k rows in Column A. Is there a faster way to loop through?

Comment: Yes put everything in arrays and only write back to the sheet once all done.

Comment: The range thing has worked perfectly! Thank you so much. 
The second issue I had was, for words like progress and state it also includes for words like progressive and statement.

Comment: See my comment above - think you'll need regular expressions.

Comment: To search for whole words prefix and suffix your search terms with a space. Note 1: if you have anything other than space between words, replace them with space.  Note 2: preprocess your lists outside your main loop. You don't want to do that 40 million times

Answer (score -1):

I have written a Python code which I thought might help.

```
def string_contains_exact(column_a, split_keyword):
    # I am an american merchant ofcourse
    # american merchant
    if not split_keyword:
        return True

    for index in range(len(column_a)):
        if split_keyword[0] == column_a[index]:
            if string_contains_exact(column_a[index+1:], split_keyword[1:]):
                return True
    return False

def subset_if_present(input_data, keyword_set):
    result = []

    for row_ind in range(len(input_data)):
        column_a = input_data[row_ind][0].lower().split()

        for keyword in keyword_set:
            split_keyword = keyword.split()

            if string_contains_exact(column_a, split_keyword):
                result.append((input_data[row_ind], keyword))

    return result

input_data = [
    ['I have sample', 'b0', 'c0'],
    ['I have discover card', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['I am enterprise', 'b2', 'c2'],
    ['I have nothing', 'b3', 'c3'],
    ['I have everything', 'b4', 'c4'],
    ['Can I paywhere', 'b5', 'c5'],
    ['what airport', 'b6', 'c6'],
    ['who are you', 'b7', 'c7'],
    ['what are the names', 'b8', 'c8'],
    ['who is the manufacturer', 'b9', 'c9'],
    ['where is it most accepted', 'b10', 'c10'],
    ['what names', 'b11', 'c11'],
    ['is the network down', 'b12', 'c12'],
    ['what state are you from', 'b13', 'c13'],
    ['when is the statement available', 'b14', 'c14'],
    ['how good is the progress', 'b15', 'c15'],
    ['are you progressive', 'b16', 'c16']
]
keyword_set = ["discover", "american merchant", "enterprise", "sample",
"hardware", "progress", "payanywhere", "acquirers", "airport",     "annual","certified", "manufacturers", "most accepted", "names", "networks", "state"]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(subset_if_present(input_data, keyword_set))
```

This prints the rows along with the keyword that occurred in each of these rows. Sorry but I don't know VBA. Hope this helps.